# npm SCSS not compiling

Tags: css, node.js, npm, sass

I have installed NPM correctly and written my main.scss file which I need to compile. My "package.json" file looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "recreated-site",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "bootstrap.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "compile:sass": "node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.css"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "sass": "^1.26.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^4.13.1"
  }
}
```

Upon running the command "npm run compile:sass" I get this error message:

> An output directory must be specified when compiling a directory
>   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>   npm ERR! errno 1
>   npm ERR! recreated-site@1.0.0 compile:sass: `node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.css`
>   npm ERR! Exit status 1
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! Failed at the recreated-site@1.0.0 compile:sass script.
>   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>   npm ERR!     C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-03-08T09_13_28_740Z-debug.log

I have no idea what I did wrong as I am new to SASS. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're running on Windows, which uses backslashes `\` instead of forward slashes `/`.

Replace your blackslashes by forward slashes in your package.json like this :

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "compile:sass": "node-sass sass\main.scss css\style.css"
},
```

BTW, I'm not sure `&&` and `exit 1` works on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I was using react-js.
After the changes in scss and compiled it again using npm command and it worked for me.
[image: Check the image below]

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 0):

During defining `scripts` , In my case ,I just deleted The `test` line and only kept the `compile:sass` line. Below is my used `scripts` in `JSON` file:

```
    "compile:sass":"node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.css -w"
  }
```

After saving it , I open `CMD` at project location and run the command `npm run compile:sass`.

**Hope this helps**

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, you might encounter this problem when you donot give the correct path for your sass file which you want to compile. Double check the path from the packagejson to your main sass file you want to compile.